# Managing no-client area

Tags: windows, qt, winapi

I've been searching a long time ago for a manner to enhance and skin the no-client area in windows, and many people say that there are only two ways, either you make a frame-less window and draw my own buttons or by hooking windows message like WM_PAINT, and I'm interested in the second approach, so is there anyway to achieve that because the big problem is that I'm using Qt, and maybe this photo will help emphasizing the problem.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is Non-client painting.  Windows has a number of messages for handling the non-client area.  Doing some web searches for 'QT Non-client paint' results in [this thread](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/3331/), which gives a brief example of how to do non-client painting in QT.

Comment: already found that, I need something new and exactly how to achieve the same look as the picture above.

Comment: however, I tried to port the code above to Qt 5 and here's what I've got http://i.stack.imgur.com/FAKbv.png

P.S: I'm using win 7

Comment: You also need to handle [WM_ACTIVATE](http://customerborderform.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Painting%20NonClient%20Area&ProjectName=customerborderform); also, theming may be active, in which case you may well decide to turn off theming entirely; there's a nice article about the raw APIs involved on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb688195%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: that can't help it's pure MFC how can I port such functionalities to Qt

Comment: @pourjour - the MSDN article is raw win32.  If you don't understand the underlying substrate, you'll never get it working with your toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Brackets (specifically the CEF wrapper source code, found here: https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/) provides source code for non-client painting; Spotify shares this code (see credits).  I do not have experience with doing this in Qt; I tinkered with a 64-bit port of brackets-shell but didn't finish as I started playing with Electron.  It's Windows specific, so maybe you could use Win32 API directly to wrap the Qt window's WndProc and implement that way?